# Testing email sending in Django

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, django-testing

I need to test that my Django application sends e-mails with correct content. I don't want to rely on external systems (like an ad-hoc [gmail](https://mail.google.com/mail/) account), since I'm not testing the actual e-mail service...

I would like to, maybe, store the emails locally, within a folder as they are sent.
Any tip on how to achieve it?

Comment: Moderators: please lock this question. Lots of spam is being added in the answers, proposing solutions that are ridiculously complex just to promote external services.

Comment: It's all in the docs now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#email-services

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use a [file backend for sending emails](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#file-backend) which is a very handy solution for development and testing; emails are not sent but stored in a folder you can specify!

Comment: More info about email backends: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#email-backends.
Sometimes even simple console backend is enough..

Comment: But is there a way to access the generated email during (automated) testing ?

Comment: @Overdrivr you could use a `print` statement to see the generated email in the terminal(e.g. `print("Mailbox\n", mail.outbox[0].message(), "\n", "_" * 80)` this can be placed before or after any `assert` statements. `self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)`

Answer (score 217):

Django test framework has some built in helpers to aid you with testing [e-mail service](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#email-services).

Example from docs (short version):

```
from django.core import mail
from django.test import TestCase

class EmailTest(TestCase):
    def test_send_email(self):
        mail.send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.',
            'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False)
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
        self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].subject, 'Subject here')
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. But I it's not useful for complex cases, when `send_mail` can't be used.

Comment: More precisely the doc is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#in-memory-backend

Comment: How would you do this if your testing a function which calls send_mail and you therefore can't access `mail`?

Comment: @MatthewDrill you can still access `mail.outbox` when `send_mail` is called in another function.

Comment: @pymarco If you import mail from core, `mail.outbox[0].body` will show you the email sent even if the `send_mail` is performed elsewhere.

Comment: This works perfect even with mass sending using send_messages, here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#sending-multiple-emails

Answer (score 28):

If you are into unit-testing the best solution is to use the [In-memory backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#in-memory-backend) provided by django.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
```

Take the case of use it as a **py.test** fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def email_backend_setup(self, settings):
    settings.EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
```

In each test, the `mail.outbox` is reset with the server, so there are no side effects between tests.

```
from django.core import mail

def test_send(self):
    mail.send_mail('subject', 'body.', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'])
    assert len(mail.outbox) == 1

def test_send_again(self):
    mail.send_mail('subject', 'body.', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'])
    assert len(mail.outbox) == 1
```

Answer (score 11):

**2024 update:** MailHog sadly seems to be unmaintained since 2020. I saw [axllent/mailpit](https://github.com/axllent/mailpit) being recommended here and there, but I haven't used it myself yet.

---

Use **[MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog)**

> Inspired by MailCatcher, easier to install.
>
> Built with Go - MailHog runs without installation on multiple platforms.

Also, it has a component called **Jim**, the **MailHog Chaos Monkey**, which enables you to test sending emails with various problems happening:

> What can Jim do?
>
> - Reject connections
> - Rate limit connections
> - Reject authentication
> - Reject senders
> - Reject recipients

Read more about it [here](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/blob/master/docs/JIM.md).

(Unlike original mailcatcher, which [failed on me when sending emails with emoji, encoded in UTF-8](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/285) and it WASN'T really fixed in the current release, MailHog just works.)

Answer (score 5):

For any project that doesn't require sending attachments, I use [django-mailer](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer), which has the benefit of all outbound emails ending up in a queue until I trigger their sending, and even after they've been sent, they are then logged - all of which is visible in the Admin, making it easy to quickly check what you emailing code is trying to fire off into the intertubes.

Comment: Further to that, the Message objects created by django-mailer mean you can prod them (and inspect their contents) in unit tests too (I know that there's outbound mailbox support in the test suite for a dummy mailbox, but using django-mailer doesn't send mail unless the management command sends it, which means you can't use that mailbox object)

Comment: Update, ages on from my original answer: https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-mailer-2 does support attachments, too

Answer (score 4):

Django also has an in-memory email backend. More details in the docs under [In-memory backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/#in-memory-backend). This is present in Django 1.6 not sure if it's present in anything earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Patching SMTPLib for testing purposes can help test sending mails without sending them.

- http://www.psychicorigami.com/2007/09/20/monkey-patching-pythons-smtp-lib-for-unit-testing/

Answer (score 1):

Why not start your own really simple SMTP Server by inherit from [`smtpd.SMTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtpd.html) and [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

```
class TestingSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer, threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, port=25):
        smtpd.SMTPServer.__init__(
            self,
            ('localhost', port),
            ('localhost', port),
            decode_data=False
        )
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data, **kwargs):
        self.received_peer = peer
        self.received_mailfrom = mailfrom
        self.received_rcpttos = rcpttos
        self.received_data = data

    def run(self):
        asyncore.loop()
```

process_message is called whenever your SMTP Server receive a mail request, you can do whatever you want there.

In the testing code, do something like this:

```
smtp_server = TestingSMTPServer()
smtp_server.start()
do_thing_that_would_send_a_mail()
smtp_server.close()
self.assertIn(b'hello', smtp_server.received_data)
```

Just remember to [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncore.html#asyncore.dispatcher.close) the [`asyncore.dispatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncore.html#asyncore.dispatcher) by calling `smtp_server.close()` to end the asyncore loop(stop the server from listening).

Answer (score 1):

Tying a few of the pieces here together, here's a straightforward setup based on `filebased.EmailBackend`. This renders a list view linking to the individual log files, which have conveniently timestamped filenames. Clicking a link in the list displays that message in the browser (raw):

**Settings**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = f"{MEDIA_ROOT}/email_out"
```

**View**

```
import os

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render

def mailcheck(request):

    path = f"{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/email_out"
    mail_list = os.listdir(path)

    return render(request, "mailcheck.html", context={"mail_list": mail_list})
```

**Template**

```
{% if mail_list %}
  <ul>
  {% for msg in mail_list %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}email_out/{{msg}}">{{ msg }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  No messages found.
{% endif %}
```

**urls**

```
path("mailcheck/", view=mailcheck, name="mailcheck"),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a TomCat server available, or other servlet engine, then a nice approach is "Post Hoc" which is a small server that looks to the application exactly like a SMTP server, but it includes a user interface that allows you to view and inspect the email messages that were sent.   It is open source and freely available.

Find it at: [Post Hoc GitHub Site](https://github.com/agilepro/posthoc)

See the blog post:  [PostHoc: Testing Apps that Send Email](https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/posthoc-testing-apps-that-send-email/)